# Does the Force Have Color That Can Be Seen?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

I researched this question on SE and Wookieepedia for a couple of hours before posting, to ensure it hasn't been asked before. I read up on the Force on Wookieepedia, as well as the Jedi and the Sith and Yoda and the ysalamir that can repel the Force, but I couldn't find a ***physical description*** of the Force.

I've been wondering whether or not the Force *could* be seen and, given Wookieepedia's description of "aura lights" of the Force, I wondered if the Force has color, like an aural spectrum or a hologram, that can be seen by those who are Force-sensitive and highly specialized in detecting the Force. And, if so, would the color of a Jedi or Sith's lightsaber reflect what color that individual sees the Force in?

Comment: What exactly are you talking about when you say "like an aural spectrum"?

Comment: @DVK An First, an aura is this: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KaepyJppoCg/Tt6vEjAR6TI/AAAAAAAAAJU/gn1uSqjgiCo/s1600/aura.jpg. An aural spectrum is all the colors an aura holds -- some auras hold only one color, other appear as rainbow or prism-like. It's like the rainbow glimpses you see when turning a card or cover with a hologram on it.

Comment: There is [force sight](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_sight), which is where you see *with the Force*. In the KOTOR games, you could see an entity's alignment (light/dark) with force sight as well, though the canonicity of that is suspect. Still, that's about as close as you're going to get to 'seeing the Force'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Q: *...would the color of a Jedi or Sith's lightsaber reflect what color that individual sees the Force in?*

A: **No**. Lightsaber blade color depended entirely on the [crystal](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lightsaber_crystal#Known_color_crystals) used to focus it.

---

As far as the force having color: It's similar to sounds. All the perception of all senses - including midichlorian-provided Force sense - happens in the brain. The brain doesn't **normally** see sounds as colors, nor tastes, nor heat - nor would it the Force.

**However**, there are people who are known to have some neural wires crossed who actually are able to see non-visual senses as colors ([Synesthesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesthesia)) - by analogy, it's not impossible to have a Force Sensitive who'd have the same with the Force. **But**, that would be an exceptionally rare aberration, I never heard of such in the canon, and even if that happened, it wouldn't have been a true "color" of the Force but merely that person's brain's perception.

Comment: The condition you're talking about is called Synesthesia http://synesthete.org/ and there are five types http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesthesia. It's not *as* rare as one might think, but, true, it doesn't reflect the general population per se. Would it be possible that the Force is only visible at certain angles, like a hologram?

Comment: @Slytherincess - No. It doesn't interact with electromagnetic spectrum as far as I'm aware (or rather there's no information in canon to suggest so AFAIK), which is what "visible" requires.

Comment: This is correct.  The sith have red blades due to the type of crystal that only sith have access to.  A sith could choose to use a different crystal but these crystals are powerful.

Answer (score 1):

The force is a force, like Gravity, Electromagnetic, etc. Those forces cannot be seen, and neither can the force.

There are detectors which can sense normal forces, like gravity, and there are people sensitive to the Force. Presumably one could make a device that is sensitive to the force, but I've never heard of such a device.

Comment: Here you go.  One [Force Detector](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_detector), ready for action.

Comment: @Jeff - sorry, you're wrong. This device didn't detect **The Force** - it detected **Force Sensitivity** - basically, Midichlorian counts.

Comment: Well, electromagnetism can be seen -- in fact it's the only thing that can.  Light is electromagnetic radiation.

Comment: @Keith: I suppose you could interperet that like that.

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto I think that's the way physics interperets it...

Answer (score 1):

No.
It's reasonable because the Force isn't a physical object with mass to hold a color attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the Force is usually colorless, it isn't Harry Potter magic. However Spirit Ichor, an extension of the Force conjured by the Nightsisters, is always green. If you count the Force Unleashed expressions of the Force Wave power then perhaps strong manifestations of the Force are blue in color.

Answer (score 0):

George Lucas himself had commented on this. The Force is not visual, you just feel it. The only place it can be seen is in the video games, just for gaming purposes (and it is generally a bright blue depending on what ability you are using).

Comment: When/Where did he say that?